# Docker container ignoring folder within directory

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, microservices, docker-volume

I've created a docker container to run a spring boot application, that when ran on the localhots requires access to a folder containing a number  files. when i built the docker image , i copied the folder with these files into the container.

As you can see the folder appears to be present but the application seems to have to trouble locating the /messaging folder
[container directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FriP.png)

Heres the error i get:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rdkgz.png)

below is the docker-compose i created to connect everything together.

```
   version: '2.1'

services:
  zoo1:
    image: zookeeper:3.4.9
    hostname: zoo1
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
    environment:
        ZOO_MY_ID: 1
        ZOO_PORT: 2181
        ZOO_SERVERS: server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/data:/data
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/zoo1/datalog:/datalog

  kafka1:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:5.4.1
    hostname: kafka1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
      - "19092:19092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL://kafka1:19092,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL://kafka1:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,LISTENER_DOCKER_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: LISTENER_DOCKER_INTERNAL
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: "zoo1:2181"
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      #KAFKA_LOG4J_LOGGERS: "kafka.controller=INFO,kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler=INFO,state.change.logger=INFO"
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
    volumes:
      - ./zk-single-kafka-single/kafka1/data:/var/lib/kafka/data
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
      
  List_service:
  
    image: list-service
    ports:
     - "8089:8089"
     
    environment:
       KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPADDRESS: kafka1:19092
       #KEYCLOAK_AUTH-SERVER-URL : "localhost:8080/auth"
      
       KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
     
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - zoo1
      
      
     
  filter-service:
  
    image: filter-service
   
    ports:
     - "8090:8090"
     
    environment:
       KAFKA_BOOTSTRAPADDRESS: kafka1:9092
       KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
       FMP_HOME: /
    
    depends_on:
      - kafka1
      - zoo1
```

Comment: "application seems to have to trouble locating the folder." Update your question with the errors.   How are you trying to read this folder?

Comment: I've added a new image that contains the error message, hopefully that gives more insight

Comment: the docker-compose file isn't relevant unless you meant to map your local path to the container that is being run. Add the Dockerfile, I assume for list-service, and we'll be able to see how you "copied in" the messaging directory